# Good and reliable practice to get a Node.js client to connect to a gremlin-server (all running on the same server) for CRUD operations

Tags: node.js, connection, janusgraph, gremlin-server

[On Ubuntu 18.04]
I have (and am constrained to use) **janusgraph** to create a persona repository. I will be using a graphDB, largely because persona relationships are as important as persona attributes and the structure needs to be fluid. I need to create a Node.js application (+ pug & stylus eventually) to do **CRUD** operations on the data in the graphDB but I don't understand how to connect the client to the server. (Research has shown solutions for this problem but only with different components in place - *Neo4j*, *OrientDB*, etc)

I can start **gremlin-server** successfully and then I have tried creating a **gremlin-console** connection such as the following

`/opt/janusgraph-0.2.2-hadoop2/bin/gremlin.sh /opt/janusgraph-0.2.2-hadoop2/conf/gremlin-server/gremlin-server.yaml`

where the yaml looks like this:

(As well as `localhost`, I also tried the host's specific IP address, and both options with and without the square brackets, but with similar results)

```
host: [localhost]
port: 8182
scriptEvaluationTimeout: 30000
channelizer: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.channel.WebSocketChannelizer
graphs: {
  graph: conf/gremlin-server/janusgraph-cql-es-server.properties
}
plugins:
  - janusgraph.imports
scriptEngines: {
  gremlin-groovy: {
    imports: [java.lang.Math],
    staticImports: [java.lang.Math.PI],
    scripts: [scripts/empty-sample.groovy]}}
serializers:
  - { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GryoMessageSerializerV1d0, config: { ioRegistries: [org.janusgraph.graphdb.tinkerpop.JanusGraphIoRegistry] }}
  - { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GryoLiteMessageSerializerV1d0, config: {ioRegistries: [org.janusgraph.graphdb.tinkerpop.JanusGraphIoRegistry] }}
  - { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GryoMessageSerializerV1d0, config: { serializeResultToString: true }}
  - { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GraphSONMessageSerializerGremlinV1d0, config: { ioRegistries: [org.janusgraph.graphdb.tinkerpop.JanusGraphIoRegistryV1d0] }}
  - { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GraphSONMessageSerializerGremlinV2d0, config: { ioRegistries: [org.janusgraph.graphdb.tinkerpop.JanusGraphIoRegistry] }}
  - { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GraphSONMessageSerializerV1d0, config: { ioRegistries: [org.janusgraph.graphdb.tinkerpop.JanusGraphIoRegistryV1d0] }}
processors:
  - { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.op.session.SessionOpProcessor, config: { sessionTimeout: 28800000 }}
  - { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.op.traversal.TraversalOpProcessor, config: { cacheExpirationTime: 600000, cacheMaxSize: 1000 }}
metrics: {
  consoleReporter: {enabled: true, interval: 180000},
  csvReporter: {enabled: true, interval: 180000, fileName: /tmp/gremlin-server-metrics.csv},
  jmxReporter: {enabled: true},
  slf4jReporter: {enabled: true, interval: 180000},
  gangliaReporter: {enabled: false, interval: 180000, addressingMode: MULTICAST},
  graphiteReporter: {enabled: false, interval: 180000}}
maxInitialLineLength: 4096
maxHeaderSize: 8192
maxChunkSize: 8192
maxContentLength: 65536
maxAccumulationBufferComponents: 1024
resultIterationBatchSize: 64
writeBufferLowWaterMark: 32768
writeBufferHighWaterMark: 65536
```

The stdout looks like this:

```
         (o o)
-----oOOo-(3)-oOOo-----
plugin activated: janusgraph.imports
plugin activated: tinkerpop.server
plugin activated: tinkerpop.utilities
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/opt/janusgraph-0.2.2-hadoop2/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.12.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/opt/janusgraph-0.2.2-hadoop2/lib/logback-classic-1.1.2.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
16:19:01 WARN  org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCodeLoader  - Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
plugin activated: tinkerpop.hadoop
plugin activated: tinkerpop.spark
plugin activated: tinkerpop.tinkergraph
Error in /opt/janusgraph-0.2.2-hadoop2/conf/gremlin-server/gremlin-server.yaml at [1: host: [localhost]] - No such property: localhost for class: groovysh_evaluate
```

Clearly, I've assumed or configured something(s) incorrectly, even in the console to server yaml and I don't know if the same yaml file would work for a Node.js client to connect.

I think I want the console connection so I can import the starter data from a graphml file and thereafter create new entries, query them, update them & delete them from the front end Node.js application.

What do I need to do to ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following doesn't create any connections from Gremlin Console to Gremlin Server:

```
/opt/janusgraph-0.2.2-hadoop2/bin/gremlin.sh /opt/janusgraph-0.2.2-hadoop2/conf/gremlin-server/gremlin-server.yaml
```

`gremlin.sh` does not take a Gremlin Server yaml file as an argument. Simply start `bin/gremlin.sh` and then write connect commands:

```
gremlin> :remote connect tinkerpop.server conf/remote.yaml
```

where `remote.yaml` points at Gremlin Server. You can read more about this in detail in a variety of places but I'll just point you to the TinkerPop reference documentation [here](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#connecting-via-console).

Comment: Thank you. That got me over the issue.